# adding favicons in golem

Tags: r, shiny, golem

the [R documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/golem/versions/0.1/topics/use_favicon) shows the code for adding a favicon to a shiny app developed with the golem package as:

```
golem::use_favicon(path="inst/app/www/favicon.ico", method = "curl")
```

My question: where do I insert this code?
When running it in the console or within the 02_dev.R file, I receive the following message:

```
✔ favicon.ico created at /srv/shiny-server/modelCostOfOwnership/inst/app/www/favicon.ico
Favicon is automatically linked in app_ui via `golem_add_external_resources()`
```

I'd assume it is working.  With the following code in the ui, the default golem favicon is gone, but the new favicon (replacing the original favicon.ico) is not appearing.

```
tags$head(tags$link(rel="shortcut icon", href="favicon.ico"))
```

Comment: Hi, which golem version du you use? Is your application publicly available?

Comment: @VincentGuyader I think I solved my own problem by creating a reproducible example (funny how that works). Here is the example: (https://golemplayground.shinyapps.io/golemplayground/). you can see the globe favicon instead of the golem.  app verson is 0.2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I had was saving the .ico file to the /www folder.
keeping the .ico in a folder called /new_favicon and calling 
`golem::use_favicon(path="new_favicon/favicon.ico", method = "curl")` worked!

Comment: thanks, I will look closer to this to be sure it's not an issue.

Comment: it can be done simply by specifying your file name in the `ico` argument of `favicon()` function in the `app_ui.R` file

Comment: thanks @AJIMA, but the quirk for me was only happening when using the golem package format for app development. For a non-golem app, favicon() works just fine.